# installing fontawesome 5.2.0 in Asp.Net Core 2.1.0

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core-2.1, font-awesome-5

I have installed `"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.2.0"` through `package.json` to my new project. It installs in root directory `node_modules\@fontawesome\etc.`

Now that I have added this to my `_Layout.cshtml` like `<link href="~/vendor/fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Now fonts are not working as supporting files were installed under folder `@fontawesome`. If I change from `@fontawesome` to `fontawesome` it works well but system re-installing entire supporting files again to `node_modules\@fontawesome\etc.`

Please suggest a way to avoid this.

Here is my `startup.cs` file

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"node_modules")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/vendor")
        });
```

If I link as it is path like `<link href="~/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />` the error is `"The name fortawesome does not exist in current context."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed `@fontawesome` to `fontawesome` and made my link as 
`<link href="~/vendor/fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

System re-installed to `@fontawesome`, I just `uninstalled fontawesome` from `npm` has uninstalled newly created folder with `@fontawesome` but physical files available for that of I renamed.

Its working fine for me. And Yes, this may not be the correct way but it works.

Comment: it is indeed the '@' in `@font-awesome-free` that is causing the issue. Good work around @Ramesh.